# MYSQL database not showing inserted data from HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP and I was following a simple tutorial on youtube, I followed the youtube video, double and tripple checked to make sure everything I typed was correct and data was still not being inserted.

I searched the internet for hours and I came up with a fix, sort of but I don't think it's the correct way to do it

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Insert Form Data In MYSQL Database Using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">

    Name : <input type="text" name="username">
            <br/>
    Email : <input type="text" name="email">
            <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$con) {
    echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'tutorial')) {
    echo 'Database Not Selected';
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $Name = $_POST['username'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('John', 'john@gmail.com')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo 'Not Inserted';
} else {
    echo 'Inserted Successfully!';
}
header("refresh:10; url=index.html");
?>
```

I replaced '$Name' and '$Email' with John and john@gmail.com, then I type it into the html form and the data goes into the database correctly.

I then found another HTML form online with more PHP but it does the same thing(not inserting any data to the database)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Record Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert1.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastname']);
$email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The fields are blank, any help will be greatly appreacited!

Btw This is how the fields display I'm using xampp server.

[image]

Comment: Quite a good way to test as you go is to echo the varibles to check your progress. For example, echo $first_name . " " . $last_name . " " . $email_address; after they are declared, and echo $sql; after it is created. Do you get what you expect?

Comment: So what messages do you get from either of these bits of code

Comment: I note they are both connecting to different databases. Do you have a database called `tutorial` and/or one called `demo`

Comment: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\insert1.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\insert1.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\insert1.php on line 14
Records added successfully.


edit, and yes I am testing 2 different databases.

Comment: That would have been useful information to put in your original questions, now wouldn't it!

Comment: Your first example does not have `name="something"` attributes on the HTML input fields so NOTHING will be passed to the PHP script.

Comment: I am afraid I have to mention this: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Well I followed this tutorial and his data inserted but mine didn't https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BoZc5oUioA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used the below code and it works fine for me.

```
  <?php

     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dummy");

      // Check connection
     if($link === false){
     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
     }

 /* Collect below values from $_POST
 $firstname = 'John';
 $lastname = 'Doe';
 $email = 'test@gmail.com';
 */
   // Escape user inputs for security
  $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $firstname);
  $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $lastname);
  $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);

  // attempt insert query execution
     $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (account_firstname, account_lastname, account_email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";
   if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
       echo "Records added successfully.";
     } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }

    // close connection
     mysqli_close($link);
     ?>
```

Comment: Accounts table I had used for demo, please use your table name and column names.

Comment: Still blank.. Notice: Undefined variable: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\insert1.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\insert1.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\insert1.php on line 18
Records added successfully.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work now, but with every name I then have to type the name and emails into the php code first, then submit via the html form, I thought there would be a simple way to use the html form only to insert the data to the database, but thanks.

Comment: So I figured out my .HTACCESS file was what's causing the blank fields in the tables in the DB, I had used it to remove  .php extensions from files, but after removing the htaccess file from my web directory the forms work as they should, just had to post this in case it helps anyone else in the future.